# Is generating ruby docs (ri, rdocs) via RVM gemset specific?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rdoc, gemset, ri

Using RVM I can generate docs using:

```
rvm docs generate
```

My question is do I have to do this for every gemset, or is it global?

I frequently switch gemsets while working on different projects.  I would like to have ri always available. Does the above command generate the docs for all gemsets or just the current one?

It seems that the docs would have to be gemset specific so that different gems and versions of gems would be documented correctly in the environment you are in. Is the `rvm docs` command smart enough to make sure every gemset has documentation, or must I re-run this command for each gemset?

Comment: This really seems like something you could very easily test. Create a gemset with no gems, change to it, then see what `ri` tells you.

Comment: Yes, but I have quite a number of gemsets using different versions of ruby and the first generation I started over an hour ago is still running.  I didn't want to have to do the generation multiple times if it could be avoided.

Comment: it is configured in .gemrc `gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc`

Comment: @phoet yes I have that in my .gemrc.  That prevents the documentation from being created at gem install time (which is a good thing as it speeds installation tremendously). What I want is to batch process the creation of the documentation.

Comment: @theTimMan so I did test and discovered that the document generation is gemset specific.  You have to generate the docs for each gemset.  I wound up wring a simple bash loop to load each gemset and then run the generate command, overnight.

Comment: why do you even want that documentation? browsing the source directly is so much better anyways.